# Can't execute gem from Capistrano on RVM Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, path, rvm, capistrano

I have a Rails app deployed to Ubuntu with RVM via Capistrano3.

I am trying to use Eye gem but can not execute it. It is installed via RVM on Ubuntu and I can run it on Ubuntu just fine.

```
namespace :eye do



  desc 'Load Eye'


  task :load do
    on roles(:app) do

      execute "cd #{current_path} && eye load #{current_path}/lib/tasks/conductor.eye"
    end
  end

end
```

The error I am getting is :

```
    bash: eye: command not found
```

cap aborted!

If I do bundle exec I get same error for bundler..

If I run echo $PATH via Capistrano I get:

```
 BUG [f84df590] Command: echo $PATH
 DEBUG [f84df590]   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

while $PATH on Ubuntu is :

```
  /home/cmsapplication/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/home/cmsapplication/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/home/cmsapplication/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/cmsapplication/.rvm/bin:/home/cmsapplication/.rvm/bin
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require "whenever/capistrano"

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: Do you have `require 'capistrano/rvm'` in your `Capfile`?

Comment: yes and I can deploy just fine, it's Capistrano 3

Comment: Can you add your Capfile to the question?

Comment: not familiar with rvm and only a bit with cap but in general this seems like a problem that might be solved by replacing `eye` with `\`which eye\``.

Comment: this failed with "exit status: 1" and no other info

Comment: Do you have the files `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` for the user `cmsapplication` containing your PATH settings? If not try `https://github.com/joshfng/railsready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the files:

~/.bash_profile

```
    [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

    source ~/.profile

    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
    export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

~/.profile

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And change the line in your task from

```
execute "cd #{current_path} && eye load #{current_path}/lib/tasks/conductor.eye"
```

to

```
execute "cd #{current_path} && /bin/bash --login -c 'eye load #{current_path}/lib/tasks/conductor.eye'"
```

Comment: Please try to change `eye load #{current_path}/lib/tasks/conductor.eye` to `/bin/bash --login -c eye load #{current_path}/lib/tasks/conductor.eye`

Comment: but it does not recognize the parameters - eye gets called but not eye load

Comment: Try `/bin/bash --login -c 'eye load #{current_path}/lib/tasks/conductor.eye'`, please. I forgot the `'`